# ODE with Euler Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eulers-method

I have to solve the following ODE: $y'(t)=y(t)+t$, $y(0)=0$
with Eulers Method in two steps, where $h=0.1$. I tried the following:
$y'(0)=y(0)+0=0$ and then I get $y(0.1)=y(0)+h*y'(0)=0$ but then everything will be 0. I do not get how to solve this.

Comment: $y=0$ is the solution for initial condition $y(0)=0$. Choose a more *interesting* initial condition e.g. $y(0)=1$ and try again.

Comment: @xidgel : No, there is a non-zero forcing term, the general solution is $y(t)=ce^t-1-t$ and $c=1$ for $y(0)=0$.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the next step you get $f(0.1, 0)=0.1$ so that you get a non-zero value for the approximation at $0.2$.

---

The leading error coefficient in $y_k=y(t_k)+c(t_k)h+O(h^2)$ is a solution of $$c'(t)=f_y(t,y)c-\frac12y''=c-\frac12e^t, \\~~\text{ so that }~~
(e^{-t}c)'=-\frac12\implies c(t)=-\frac12te^t
$$

Plotting the actual error coefficient $\frac{y_k-y(t_k)}h$ against this first term curve for several values of $h$ gives the image

[image]

So that indeed the Euler points are below the exact solution, for large $h$ this can be a large error, and for $h=0.1$ the error is as large as the value of the solution.